# Regularity of harmonic functions for a degenerate elliptic operator

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-processes, elliptic-pde, potential-theory

This is a question on a degenerate elliptic operator.

Let $E$ be a **closed** unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$ centered at the origin. For a positive number $c>0$ and $f \in C^2(E)(:=C^2(\mathbb{R}^d)|_E)$, we
define
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}f(x)=(1-|x|^2)\Delta f(x)-c\times(x,\nabla f(x)),\quad x \in E.
\end{align*}
Here, $|x|$ denotes the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^d$. For an open subset $U \subset E$, a harmonic function $h$ on $U$ (with respect to $(\mathcal{L},C^2(E))$) should be properly introduced. That is, $h$ belongs to $C^2(U)$ and satisfies  $\mathcal{L}h=0$ on $U$ (perhaps it should be formulated in a slightly weaker sense).

Let $z \in \partial E$ and $r \in (0,1)$, and set $U=E \cap B(z,r)$. Here, $B(z,r)$ denotes the  open ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$ centered at $z$ with radius $r>0$. We consider a harmonic function $h$ on $U$ (with respect to $(\mathcal{L},C^2(E))$) which satisfies the Dirichlet boundary condition: $h=0$ on $B(z,r)\cap \partial E$.

**My question.**

- Does such a harmonic function exist in the first place?
  (Although I can define  such  a function in a probabilistic sense, I do not know it is $C^2$ on $U$.)
- If it exists, can we study the regularity of $\nabla h$ on $U$?

I feel that it is difficult to study harmonic functions for degenerated differential operators like $(\mathcal{L},C^2(E))$. Please let me know if there is any related preceding research.

**A probabilistic counterpart of this question**

It is known that $(\mathcal{L},C^2(E))$ generates a diffusion process $X$ on $E$. For exmaple, if $c=0$, the diffusion process $X$ can be regarded as a time-changed (absorbing) Brownian motion on $E$. If $c\ge 2$, the diffusion process $X$ never hit the boundary when the starting point is an  interior point of $E$. However, if $c \in (0,2)$, $X$ reaches the boundary even when the starting point is an  interior point of $E$. Thus, I think the properties of the harmonic functions with respect to $\mathcal{L}$ will change (in a sense) depending on whether $c<2$ or  $c \ge 2$.

Comment: When you write $c>0$ and $c(x,\nabla f(x))$ you mean $c$ is any possibly unbounded function which is positive on $E\times\mathbb R^d$?

Comment: @username Thank you for your comment. $c$ is a positive constant, not function.

Comment: Do you have any restriction on the size of $c$?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thank you for your comment. I don't put any restrictions on $c$, but I'm interested in the case of $c \in (0,2)$. If $c \ge 2$, this problem should not be very interesting.

Comment: I guess that in such a case (but I should check better) the problem $Lu=0$ in $E$, $u=g$ at the boundary is uniquely solvable. Uniqueness follows from the maximum principle; concerning existence, if $g$ is smooth we can extend smoothly to $E$ and consider the problem $Lv=Lg$ in $E$ with $v=0$ at the boundary. This is the point where, I guess, you have $c<2$. The last problem can be solved in $L^p$ with the regularity depending on $c$ and $p$...I am quite sure for "small c", if $c$ is close to 2 I am less confident.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thank you very much for your very detailed comments. I'm interested in the equation $\mathcal{L}u=0$ on $E \cap B(z,r)$ with Dirichlet boundary condition on $\partial E \cap B(z,r)$  (not on $E$). I feel that this should be formulated in a slightly weaker sense. I believe that the continuity of the derivative of the solution depends on c (I wish I could know how much it was, even when $c$ was small enough). The explanation that $c = 2$ is a threshold will be added in the above question.

Comment: I noticed you want the equation to be satisfied in $U$ and actually I considered a stronger formuation. However, I have the feeling that the problem is the same and that, if you can solve locally, then you can do it globally. Do you think this is wrong?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune  I don't think it's wrong. I think the solution exists (although I can't prove this properly because $\mathcal{L}$ is degenerate). However, is the solution in the $C^2$ class up to the boundary? This is probably wrong, isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123698/discussion-between-giorgio-metafune-and-sharpe).